# Is there a word for "weaponized political correctness"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests, ambiguity

The term Political correctness is innocent enough.  According to Wikipedia:

> Political correctness is a term used to describe language, policies, or measures that are intended to avoid offense or disadvantage to members of particular groups in society.

There's nothing wrong with being cognizant of peoples' sensitivities and understanding how your words may be interpreted by others.

But political correctness also has a darker and much more sinister meaning.  In fact, the term itself is a euphemism for the kind of speech that could get you imprisoned or killed in certain countries and at certain times in history.  In this context, political correctness describes a strict adherence to an ideological orthodoxy, and is used as a cudgel to castigate others whose opinions are merely different from your own (or what I like to refer to as the crime of "Heresy against Doctrine").

Rather than being a tool for civil discourse, it becomes a weapon of war (metaphorically speaking).  This definition of "politically (in)correct" seems to be a watered-down phrase that does a disservice to what is actually going on.

Is there a specific term that is more appropriate for this usage?

Sample sentence:

> "In our current state of radical polarization, *[weaponized political correctness]* has made rational, adult conversations about important sensitive topics nearly impossible to have."

The only words I can think of are **Rhetoric** (too generic), and **newspeak** (which is a pop culture reference not really in the common lexicon.)

Comment: In my opinion, the term usually implies its negative connotations depending on the context it is used in. In your sample sentence, it can be simply used and it carries the negative tone you are aiming for. There is no need for a qualifier like 'weaponized'

Comment: I would observe that "political correctness" doesn't have a well-defined meaning.

Comment: "Newspeak" is from "Nineteen Eighty-Four" (pub. 1949). So, hardly pop culture, seeing as even pop wasn't a thing then.

Comment: @RosieF you are splitting hairs here. The *first* use of "pop" in that sense was 1947. Both *newspeak* and *pop art*, *pop culture* etc. became more widely know in the mid fifties - *newspeak* due to the 1956 movie release.

Comment: I think "weaponized political correctness" is entirely appropriate for this sort of sentence. It is a really wonderful invention. "To have" at the end is an anticlimax however. A purist would tell you to leave it out, but how about weaponizing it with something like "prosecute" or even "progress" (as a verb).

Comment: @RosieF - I disagree.  Lollipops go back to the 30s, at least.

Comment: How about "Stack Exchange Code of Conduct on Pronoun Usage"? (Sexcop, if you want it in a single word).

Comment: I'm not sure that better pithy semantics to describe a supposed preoccupation with semantics is really going to improve discourse.  Being somewhat hysterical about PC being a slippery slope to heresy trials isn't really doing them one better, ya know?

Comment: I would avoid Eurocentrism, etc. here. Obviously, political correctness depends on the state of a society's evolution. What's wrong with weaponize?

Comment: It's not actually innocent; it's mostly a dog-whistle term used by people who can't be bothered to think about the harm they're causing.

Comment: The term *political correctness*, by itself, already serves this purpose. Notwithstanding the Wikipedia definition, which makes it appear neutral or commendatory, in actual use it almost always implies some criticism.

Comment: You might be looking for the term [political repression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_repression).

Comment: "self-righteous dogmatism"

Answer (score 1):

What you described as `a strict adherence to an ideological orthodoxy, and is used as a cudgel to castigate others whose opinions are merely different from your own` is sometimes called ***censorship***.

> "In our current state of radical polarization, ***censorship*** has
>   made rational, adult conversations about important sensitive topics
>   nearly impossible to have."

Wikipedia:

> **[Censorship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship)** is the suppression of speech, public communication, or other information, on the basis that such material
>   is considered objectionable, harmful, sensitive, or "inconvenient."
>   ... It occurs in a variety of different media, including speech,
>   books, music, films, and other arts, the press, radio, television, and
>   the Internet for a variety of claimed reasons including national
>   security, to control obscenity, child pornography, and hate speech, to
>   protect children or other vulnerable groups, to promote or restrict
>   political or religious views, and to prevent slander and libel.

Answer (score 0):

I think ***extremism*** and ***dogmatism*** are good contenders. They both have the negative and political connotations you are looking for.

*Extremism*:

- > The holding of extreme political or religious views
- > A tendency or disposition to go to extremes or an instance of going to extremes, especially in political matters

  You can use '*political extremism*' if you want to be more specific.

*Dogmatism*:

- > The tendency to lay down principles as undeniably true, without consideration of evidence or the opinions of others
- > Unfounded positiveness in matters of opinion; arrogant assertion of opinions as truths

  This emphasizes the theoretical fundamentals upon which a (political) system has been built. In the context you provide, I think this still might need to be clarified, by using '*liberal dogmatism*', or something similar.

<sup>Definitions by [Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/extremism) and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/extremism), respectively.</sup>

Comment: I don’t think the term *extremism* carries the right connotation even though that’s what it amounts to. Your other suggestion, *dogmaticism*, comes closer. I think the OP is after the notion of a kind of imposed egalitarianism.